# Hiding The Gridlines On An ASP.Net Chart Control

Tags: asp.net, charts

I've made some graphs in my ASP.Net MVC application using the ASP.Net MSChart control. I cant seem to find the property for hiding the gridlines, anyone know how this is done?

Thanks

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Set the [Axis](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd455750.aspx).[MajorGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.axis.majorgrid.aspx).[Enabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.grid.enabled.aspx) property to false for the x and y axes:

```
Chart1.ChartAreas["YourChartArea"].AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
Chart1.ChartAreas["YourChartArea"].AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
```

Answer (score 5):

Its more simple than above . All you need to do is add the following lines in your aspx pageinside your chartarea , since you are using chart control.

```
            <chartareas>
                            <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
                                <axisy>
                                    <MajorGrid Enabled ="False" />
                                </axisy>
                                <axisx>
                                    <MajorGrid Enabled="false"/>
                                </axisx>
                            </asp:ChartArea>
```

You can also set the Mazor grid line width property to zero to see the same output :-

```
          <chartareas>
                            <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
                                <axisy>
                                    <MajorGrid LineWidth="0" />
                                </axisy>
                                <axisx>
                                    <MajorGrid LineWidth="0"/>
                                </axisx>
                            </asp:ChartArea>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is useful

```
Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
```